# Storage of gui data fails

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I save and load gui data as described in the manual using

```
function readImage(filename, hObject, handles)
  handles.image.data = imageRGBNoEdge;
  guidata(hObject,handles);
```

and

```
function createHistogram(handles)
  imageRGB = handles.image.data;
```

which are both called directly after the other

```
readImage(imageFile,hObject,handles);
createHistogram(handles);
```

However in he second function handles.image is unkown.

```
??? Reference to non-existent field 'image'.
Error in ==> ui_histogram>createHistogram at 252
imageRGB = handles.image.data;
```

But if I call the function a second time it is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its name, handles is a structure and not a handle class so changing it within readImage does not propagate the change to the calling function.

You could either change readImage to be

```
function handles = readImage(filename, hObject, handles)
```

and call it with

```
handles = readImage(imageFile,hObject,handles);
```

or add a call to guidata

```
handles = guidata(hObject);
```

just before your calll to createHistogram.

Comment: I was just about to write the same answer. I can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working off the assumption that `imageRGBNoEdge` is already defined at this point.

By briefly looking over the [guidata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/guidata.html) function documentation it looks like that could be part of the issue here.  When you try to load the data within `createHistogram` you need to be using something like this: `imageRGB = guidata(hObject)` because that is what tells `guidata` what data to get for you and you've already saved the data to that object handle (`hObject`)

Also, I can't really comment much more because it looks like there is also a fair bit of missing code for each of those functions.  Hopefully this will help get you going in the right direction though!

Comment: `imageRGB = guidata(hObject)` does not make much sence. the problem is that the handles object is saved in he first function using `guidata(hObject,handles)` but the `handles` variable in the calling function is a local variable and does not know that it has changed. Therefore handle must be renewed in the calling funcion, as shown in this blog post: http://www.matlabtips.com/handle-the-handles-in-guidata/

Comment: Okay, yes if you retain the `guidata(hObject, handles)` call `data` would infact be `handles`.  However if you change it to be `guidata(hObject, imageRGBNoEdge)` and pass `hObject` to `createHistogram` you should be good to go with the data in had after calling `guidata(hObject)`.